# How do I make nginx rewrite requests to a different server (which is in the same config)?

Tags: nginx, configuration, rewrite

I am trying to achieve the following: Some files on my server should be served from a subdomain (static.example.com) for performance purposes (avoiding cookies). However, some of the content is actually reachable from the main hostname as well. So for example, the file image.png would be accessible through both

`http://static.example.com/img/image.png` and

`http://www.example.com/foo/img/image.png`

I could just set an alias if this was actually all-static files, but for various config reasons I want the request to `static.example.com` to be server exactly like a request to the same file on `www.example.com`, which is defined in the same nginx config. Rewriting looks promising, but it seems like you can't rewrite "accross servers", because that would turn it into a client redirect which (probably?) defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Any pointers how to achieve this without duplicating the relevant config would be appreciated.